# Uninterrupted single cell li-ion power supply design for always on IOT device

Tags: battery-charging, batteries, industrial, iot

I am desigining an IoT vehicle tracker for industrial use. We have 2 stages of buck-LDO to get 48V to 3.3V. My aim is to build a UPS circuit so that a single cell Lipo can power the whole board when the 48V input is not available. The total current cunsumption of the board will be in between 100mA-800mA (while transmitting.)

What UPS circuitery do we have to use? Do we use a power management IC to switch from one source (li-ion), to another (48V)? Do we need to use a load switcher IC or a battery management IC?

The power source switching sould be smooth and uninterrupted and needless to say, the cell needs to be charged when the 48V is available.

I want to know what are the common industrial and robust ways to handle this problem. Just need basic design advice and we will do the in-depth research on our own.

Comment: There’s plenty of examples using input from a 5V phone charger. Then you need 48V -> 5V. Problem solved.

Comment: You mean a power Bank circuit?